# How to split a single cell in Excel into multiple cells using Python when there are line breaks within the cell?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working on a Python project that transforms a table in a PDF document to an Excel file. When converting to Excel, the function receives a list with different pandas dataframes that need to be written to the Excel sheet.
This works perfectly fine. However, sometimes the table's formatting is incorrect, leading to the presence of a line break within a single cell where there were originally two distinct cells in the original table. In the original table "This is an example" and "This is another example" are 2 different cells but what I have is this:

[image]

In such cases, I want the text to be written into separate cells like this:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this? I have tried adding the `set_text_wrap()` function, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code. In this point, I already have the list of dataframes. As you can see, it receives the list of dataframes, a sheetname for the Sheet and an output path:

```
def write_excel(list_df, sheetname, path):
    startrow = 0
    if list_df:
        try:
            book = pd.read_excel(excelpath, sheet_name=None)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            book = {}

        # df to excel
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excelpath, engine='openpyxl')
        for sheet in book:
            book[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, header=None, index=None)
        for df in list_df:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, startrow=startrow, header=None, index=None)
            startrow += (df.shape[0] + 2)
        writer.book.save(path)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks specifics but you can use [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)/[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (*& re-adapt your* `write_excel`) :

```
out = (pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
           .assign(col= lambda x: x["col"].str.split("\n"))
           .explode("col", ignore_index=True)
)

out.to_excel("new.xlsx", index=False)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                       col
0       This is an example
1  This is another example
```

[image]